# Returning a value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nedb

I wrote an angular service which querys a db and should return the Categories:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('budget')
           .service('CategoriesService', ['$q', CategoriesService]);

    function CategoriesService($q) {
        var self = this;
            self.loadCategories = loadCategories;
            self.saveCategorie = saveCategorie;
            self.datastore = require('nedb');
            self.db = new self.datastore({ filename: 'datastore/default.db', autoload : true});

        function saveCategorie (categorie_name) {
            var entry = {name: categorie_name,
                     type: 'categorie'}
            self.db.insert(entry);
        };

        function loadCategories () {
            self.db.find({type: 'categorie'}, function (err, docs) {
                var categories = docs;
                return categories;
            });
        };

        return {
            loadCategories: self.loadCategories,
            saveCategorie: self.saveCategorie
        };
    }
})();
```

When I console.log inside the `function loadCategories()` it returns me an array of 6 objects (the objects from the database) but outside of the function it just gives me `undefined`.

I am calling via the controller with `CategoriesService.loadCategories()`

So I think I might have to do something thas called `promise` but Iam not sure about that.

How can I get acctual data back from this service?

Comment: You are correct in needing a promise. Read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to return anything from the service factory recipe, you just need to assign a method to the `this` variable.

At least, you need:

```js
// service.js

self.loadCategories = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  db.find({type: 'categorie'}, function (err, docs) {
    deferred.resolve(docs);
  });
  
  return deferred.promise;
};

// controller.js

service
  .loadCategories()
  .then(function(categories) {
    $scope.categories = categories;
  })
;
```

Comment: why he wants to wrap his promise with $q?

Answer (score 1):

you need to return your promise first so just add one more return and you are good to go...

```
   function loadCategories () {
        // you need to return promise first and you can resolve your promise in your controller
        return self.db.find({type: 'categorie'}, function (err, docs) {
            var categories = docs;
            return categories;
        });
    };
```